# Prove that the set of integrable real-valued functions is a real vector space.

Tags: measure-theory

In [Folland](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160), it is said that the set of integrable real-valued functions on a measure space $(X,M,\mu)$ is a real vector space.

The proof says this follows from $|af + bg| \leq |a||f| + |b||g|$.

**Question**: from what I understand, [these are the axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) for a vector space. So how does the proposition follow from the inequality?

Comment: Well, you have to do a bit of work. Given that inequality, can you firstly prove that the sum of two integrable functions is integrable? The other parts work similarly - you need to check them all, but some are trivial.

Comment: Oh gosh. Looks like I was confused about this. You pointing out that this inequality can be used to check the vector space axioms resolved my confusion. E.g $|f+g| \leq |f| + |g|$ means that since $|f|$,$|g| < \infty$, $|f+g|$ is too and so is integrable and etc. Thanks! +1

Comment: You are welcome! Checking these things can be rather tedious, but it is something we all have to go through at least once - and it does get quicker every time :)

Comment: Just to check - the inequality is meant in the point-wise sense, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was missing was that $|af + bg| \leq |a||f| + |b||g|$ can be used to derive all the vector space axioms.

For example, we can show that if $f,g \in L^1$, then $|f|, |g| < \infty$ and so $|f+g| < |f| + |g| < \infty$ setting $a,b = 1$. Therefore, $f+g \in L^1$ too.